# Mysql query without limit not working

Tags: mysql, select, limit

Good Day,
since I using PHP to query MySQL Databases like

```
$sql = <<<SQL SELECT * FROM claims_all ORDER BY member_name, member_forename, claim_date
```

Now query a new table, I not longer get any result from the query except if I add LIMIT 0, 30 to the query (limited to 0, 50)

Is there any setting on the database to force the use of LIMIT?

Appreciate any help regards, JPB

Comment: How much data you have in database? There is no limitation on that.

Comment: What result do you get when you-  SHOW variables like 'sql_select_limit' from mysql.

Comment: Hi Justinas, the table contiens some 600 records. I try with a copy of the table, reduced to 50 records and it works without the LIMIT clause. More then 50 records get no query result.

Comment: Hi P. Salmon, no idea where to check/change this variable. The MySQL server is by Host Europe. But with two other applications, on the same MySQL server, I never got such problems

Comment: Have you referred your problem to host europe?

Comment: Not yet, perhaps a good idea, thanks

Comment: Good Day, still no answer from HE. But, with a Website X5 application I get all rows from the same database table. I dont know what Website X 15 use for the data connection.